# What does /var/named mean in this context?

Tags: linux, networking, bind

I read the following response on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/devops/comments/53qto3/what_is_your_official_job_title_some_tools_you/) in response to a question: "What are some problems at work you recently solved?"

> Hosts are in database, now there are hosts in /var/named. I mean, there were hosts in /var/named, but it was awful to manage because the admin before me didn't know how to architect (people would write text files that would become diffs which would be shuffled around from machine to machine). Soon there will be hosts in /etc/dhcpd-something.

Now I'm trying to figure out what this person is talking about. I'm wondering what does `/var/named` mean in this context? Is it a directory? A config file?

from reading on [tldp](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag2/x-087-2-resolv.named.html) I can see that `named` is a program that provides "DNS on most UNIX machines". And its config file is in `/etc/named.conf`.

When I started reading about `named` I started thinking about the `/etc/hosts` file and thought they might be conceptually related.

Comment: Please google around, BIND and /etc/hosts; also the o´reilly book BIND 9 from Cricket Liu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hosts mappings between IP address and name can be defined in `/etc/hosts`. This is similar to the original (D)ARPAnet. However, when you have more than a very few hosts it's administratively awkward to keep all the `/etc/hosts` files synchronised and uptodate.

Thus the Domain Name System or DNS was born, which provides a distributed mechanism for mapping between hosts' IP addresses and names. One particular implementation is BIND, which runs a service called `named`. Inevitably, the location of the configuration files for `named` is `/var/named`.

The big advantage of DNS over `/etc/hosts` is that you can have one or two local DNS servers for an entire local network. And those can be kept synchronised by a subsection of the DNS protocol. No more keeping `/etc/hosts` files synchronised. In fact, no editing of `/etc/hosts` at all. Furthermore, there ceases to be any difference in the way a host name or address is looked up for a local network host or one managed by another organisation is some unknown location the other side of the world. That's a benefit of a distributed solution.

If your administrator is copying files between `/var/named` directories then either they haven't grasped the distributed network nature of DNS or you've misunderstood what they're doing.

As for DHCP, there can be hosts in the DHCP configuration file but typically this would be used only for diskless clients that require support via the BOOTP protocol to boot from a network image. Software such as `dnsmasq` can manage DNS, DHCP and BOOTP all from the single configuration file, but it doesn't handle synchronisation between multiple servers.